# Bootstrap Collapse + JS Динамическое создание

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть шаблон создания кнопок, количество может быть разным. Нужно чтобы у каждой кнопки при нажатии открывался блок. Пробововал использовать скрипты JS, в них правильно задается id у раскрывающегося элемента, но не получается сменить ссылку, в итоге либо открываются все элементы, либо все кнопки открывают лишь один раздел.

```
<a class="btn btn-warning shadow-sm mb-3" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#" data-bs-target="#target">{{profile.profile}}</a>
        <div class="collapse target" id="target">
            <div class="card card-body"><a class="btn btn-warning shadow-sm mb-3">Профиль</a></div>
            <div class="card card-body"><a class="btn btn-warning shadow-sm mb-3">База</a></div>
        </div>
```

и вот такой скрипт:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            // получаем все элементы collapse
            $('.collapse').each(function (index) {
                // получаем текущий id элемент
                var id = $(this).prop('id');
                // установим этому элементу id равный текущему id + индекс
                $(this).prop('id', id + index);
                // найдём элемент в родительском, который ссылается на id и добавим к его href индекс
                $(this).parent().find('[href="#' + id + '"]').attr('href', '#' + id + index);
                $(this).parent().find('[data-bs-target="#' + id + '"]').attr('data-bs-target', '#' + id + index);

            });
        </script>
```

В результате получается вот такое:

```
<a class="btn btn-warning shadow-sm mb-3" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#" data-bs-target="#target0" aria-expanded="true">Физмат</a>
        <div class="target collapse show" id="target0" style="">
            <div class="card card-body"><a class="btn btn-warning shadow-sm mb-3">Профиль</a></div>
            <div class="card card-body"><a class="btn btn-warning shadow-sm mb-3">База</a></div>
        </div>

        
        <a class="btn btn-warning shadow-sm mb-3" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#" data-bs-target="#target0" aria-expanded="true">Гуманитарий</a>
        <div class="collapse target" id="target1">
```

Укажите на ошибки, пожалуйста

Comment: А нет возможности сделать что-то типа `<a class="btn btn-warning shadow-sm mb-3" data-bs-toggle="collapse" href="#target{{profile.id}}" data-bs-target="#target{{profile.id}}">{{profile.profile}}</a> <div class="collapse target" id="target{{profile.id}}">` ?

Comment: @br3t ты гений,получилось. Спасибо)